# Users with reading are not authorized to add likes to blog posts

Tags: blog, like

I have a blog site on Sharepoint 2013 on premises.
Most users can read only. 
Likes are enabled but when they click on "like" nothing happens.

I see on the browser develoer console that they have an error:

> Object doesn't support this action
>
> (!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined(b))b.disabled=true;var
>   a=this;EnsureScriptFunc("reputation.js","Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation",function(){var
>   b=new
>   SP.ClientContext;a.$5_0=Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(b,a.$Q_0.listName,a.$1_0,a.$8_0);b.executeQueryAsync(a.$$d_$k_0,a.$$d_$j_0)})},$k_0:function(){if(SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined(this.$5_0)||SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined(this.$5_0.get_value()))return;this.$G_0=this.$5_0.get_value().toString();this.$8_0=!this.$8_0;if(this.$8_0){SP.UI.Reputation.LikesHelpers.$y(this.$3_0,this.$D_0,this.$E_0);this.$E_0=-1}else
>   this.$E_0=SP.UI.Reputation.LikesHelpers.$m(this.$3_0,this.$D_0);var
>   d=$get(this.$Y_0);if(!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined(d)){d.innerHTML=this.renderLink(this.$9_0);var
>   b=$get(this.$9_0);if(!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined(b)){$addHandler(b

File: sp.ui.reputation.js, riga: 1, colonna: 18614

Do I need to enable them "to like" somewhere and somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try breaking inheritance for Microfeed list and giving "Edit" permission to users having "Read" permission.

Comment: I changed /Lists/PublishedFeed/AllItems.aspx this and it works. Funny that I wen back to "Read" and it still works.